# Downloading CSV file via GET to the same page

Tags: php, csv, get, http-headers

My code:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <p><input name="date_start" type="text" id="datestart" /> to
        <input name="date_end" type="text" id="dateend" /></p>
    <button type="submit">Generate!</button>
</form>
<?php
if ($_GET["date_start"] && $_GET["date_end"]) {   
    $users_list = mysql_query("my query", $dbc) or die(mysql_error());

    $output = fopen("php://output", 'w') or die("Can't open php://output");
    header("Content-Type:application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=user_list.csv");

    fputcsv($output, array("First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Mobile", "Site"));
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($users_list)) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output) or die("Can't close php://output");
}
?>
```

Basically I'm sending my FORM to the same page, below the form I check for my GET variables and try to force a CSV file download, but instead of downloading, the content of my query is simply being printed.

I think this is because my headers have already been sent, but is there a way to download the file at all?

Comment: Apart from your problem, you are using mysql which has been depricated. Use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your php code above the html form.

Comment: And especially make sure nothing has been echoed before. Or use output buffering to control whether or not to output anything.

Comment: It was rendering your form first then executing your php code.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while making my own form/CSV using POST.

Figured I would add some more info with my own example.

excerpt from my example:

```
if($_POST[submit] === "Export" && _other_test_here_ )
{
    //export CSV of all entries
    include('csv-export.php');
}
else
{
    HTML GOES HERE
    <form method="post" name="form-export" action="" onsubmit="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Export" />
        <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo($row['uid']); ?>" />
        <textarea name="comment" readonly="true" ><?php echo($row['comment']); ?></textarea>
    </form>
}
```

The included php file handles accessing the DB and outputting the CSV. Use this in your own way. I found it was nice to be able to include it from another file without any trouble.

Putting the IF and php at the top actually causes my `Export` button to not even refresh the page, the visitor simply gets a standard popup asking if they wish to open or save the CSV file. Very convenient.